# bibtex.exe an error: `I found no \citation commands---while reading file mergeS.aux`

Tags: bibtex, xetex, compilation-error

I'm trying to print this pdf file `https://shelah.logic.at/files/221770/h-v2.pdf`
which I have saved as `sh1.pdf` via this xetex code

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

\begin{document}
 
%  \includepdf[scale=1.02, nup=2x1,pages=1-8,trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{sh1.pdf}
  
  
  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-4,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{sh1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

**But I'm getting this error:**

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "mergeS"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\me\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: mergeS.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file mergeS.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file mergeS.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file mergeS.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "mergeS.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\me\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mergeS.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppxetex.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)) (./mergeS.aux)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) [1] [2]
(./mergeS.aux) )
Output written on mergeS.pdf (2 pages).
SyncTeX written on mergeS.synctex.

Transcript written on mergeS.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 2)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: For some reason you (or your editor) run BibTeX on this file. Since the file does not have a set-up for citations or a bibliography (which makes sense, because you don't need that here), BibTeX can't do its thing and throws an error. You can ignore this error. If it annoys you, don't compile your document with TeXify, but just run XeLaTeX directly.

Comment: @moewe My English is quite poor. What do you mean by `the file does not have a set-up for citations or a bibliography` ? Does this mean that my pdf book doesn't have citations and bibliography at the end ?

Comment: No, what I mean is that the TeX code you have shown does not have any LaTeX commands for citation or bibliography. It will basically just print your file `sh1.pdf`. If that PDF file has citations or a bibliography, of course that content will still be there. But this does not matter for BibTeX, which can only work with LaTeX commands for citations from your `.tex` file.

Comment: BTW: I suspect there are easier ways to print a PDF file than to include it in a TeX document even if you need to do some scaling or cropping.